# Reflection mapping in GLSL

Tags: ios, reflection, opengl-es, glsl

I'm trying to get reflection mapping with a cube map working in OpenGL ES 2.0. I'm not sure if I'm calculating the reflection direction correctly to pass to a samplerCube in the fragment shader.

To begin with I have Projection, Model and View matrices as well as a combined ModelView matrix. Here is the code for my vertex shader in GLSL:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform mat3 Model;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 EyePosition;

varying vec3 ReflectDir;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * Position;
    mediump vec3 EyeDir = normalize(Position.xyz - EyePosition);

    // Reflect eye direction by normal, and transform to world space
    ReflectDir = Model * reflect(EyeDir, Normal);
}
```

My assumptions are EyeDirection must be in object space. (Correct?)
How do I get the EyePosition in object space? Do I just transform the camera position (i.e. always at {0,0,0} in OpenGL?) by the inverse ModelView matrix?

I've tried this but my fragment shader is colouring everything black, as if the ReflectDir is incorrect.

Has anyone got a working example of OpenGL ES 2.0 reflection mapping (with a samplerCube) working in Xcode?

Comment: What is `Model`? And what is happening that is wrong when you do this?

Comment: Model is the transform matrix which gets object-space coordinates into world-space coordinates. When my object renders, it is completely black, but it is supposed to be using the ReflectDir in the fragment shader to sample the colour from a samplerCube. So, I think there is something wrong with the way I'm calculating the ReflectDir.

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach is to get both the eye direction and normal in **World coordinate system**. The lookup vector is then calculated as

`vec3 lookup = normalize(reflect(EyeDir, Normal));`